# List Comprehension: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The following code gives me: `local variable 'param' referenced before assignment`

```
value_per_label = [(label, value) \
                    for label, value in zip(gui_names(param),values) \
                    for (param, values) in parameters]
```

What am I doing wrong?

parameters looks like this:

```
parameters = [("A", (1,3,5)), ("B", (2,3,4))]
```

and I wish to convert it to:

```
value_per_label = [("A_min", 1), ("A_current", 3), ("A_max", 5), ("B_min", 2), ("B_current", 3), ("BA_max", 4)]
```

Comment: `gui_names[param]` if `gui_names` is a dictionary

Comment: @Anmol_uppal No its a function returning a tuple of "gui ids". The data being passed to me is in a wierd format so I'm converting it to something more useful.

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's convert it into a for loop (List comprehensions are basically faster, more readable for loops):

```
value_per_label = []
for label, value in zip(gui_names(param), values):
     for (param, values) in parameters:
          value_per_label.append((label, value))
```

The error is pretty obvious now

Edit: To fix it, change the for loop to this:

```
 value_per_label = [(value, label)
                    for (param, values) in parameters \
                    for (label, value) in zip(gui_names(param), values)]
```

I think this gives the same result, I didn't test it though.

Comment: Yes now I understand the issue! Thanks for your help.